# NoSuchBucketPolicy error when trying to generate Bucket Policy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying out AWS S3 for the first time and I wrote the following function to generate a bucket policy.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Load configuration
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = sails.config.accessKeyId;
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = sails.config.secretAccessKey;
AWS.config.region = sails.config.region

// Create S3 object
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Defining the required parameters
var params = {
  Bucket: "bucket-name-here"
};

s3.getBucketPolicy(params, function(error, date) {
  if(error) {
    // An error occurred
    console.log("Error\n" + error);

    return res.json({
      message: "Error",
      'error': error
    });
  } else {
    // Successful
    console.log("Data\n" + date);

    return res.json({
      message: "Successful",
      'data': date
    });
  }
});
```

But the response is always `NoSuchBucketPolicy: The bucket policy does not exist`

I tried uploading a test file into the bucket, listing all buckets and it both worked as expected. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't "generate" a bucket policy... it tries to *fetch the existing policy* of a bucket.  Buckets don't have a policy until you create one, so this error would be normal in that case.

> Error Code: NoSuchBucketPolicy
>
> Description: specified bucket does not have a bucket policy.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 404 Not Found
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Comment: Oh, my bad. So is there a way to generate a signature, policy, etc. to use for client side file uploads?

Comment: "Policy" means two different things in S3.  Bucket policy (and/or IAM user policy) statements grant or deny permissions to perform actions on buckets and objects.  Policy documents created for use with browser-based `POST` uploads define the parameters within which the upload must comply in order for S3 to consider the contents of the upload to be authorised.